# Is this function coercive? Is my method reasonable?

Tags: convex-analysis, multivariate-polynomial, coercive

Is this function coercive?

$$f(x) = (x_1+2x_2)^2$$

I thought that because, for $x=(t, -t/2)'$ (whose norm goes to infinity when t does), $f(x)=0$, that this would mean that $f$ is *not* coercive, but I'm getting conflicting answers via different methods. Does anyone have any insights? Is this method valid?

Thank you!

Comment: yes it's ok, since you found one counter example, the function is not coercive. maybe if you show the other method that gives a different answer we can help solve the confusing part.

Comment: @zwim I got some responses on Chegg that I can't find problems with: https://imgur.com/a/uHdUXZE

Comment: you can discard these, there are full of mistakes... the first one considers only $x_1,x_2\to+\infty$ completely ignoring $-\infty$ and the second one also ignores that numerator is also infinite thus having $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ which is undefined as is.

Comment: Whoever wrote "True, explanation is given in above image" should consider a different career